# Scale a PostgreSQL stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

My current implementation of a PostgreSQL stored procedure doesn't scale, though the problem could easily be split into parallel processes/threads.

---

#### The setup

An application that behaves very much alike a dating platform, i.e. users sign up, enter a couple of profile details and based on these details a matching against all other users is done. The details can be summed up to 60-70 attributes, mostly booleans, which are stored within the user record in the `user_attributes` table. So there's one large `user_attributes` table, consisting of user id and the attributes (other profile data is stored in a separate table). The attribute-by-column scheme was chosen due to performance concerns, i.e. prevent additional queries for getting all attributes of one user. For every matching, there's a per-user matching table, so every user has its own table consisting of user_id, other_user_id, matching_score.

We'd like to have up to 300k users per DB instance, but it'd be interesting to see how it could scale ten times, i.e. up to 3 million users. Beyond that, we can scale by distributing to other database instances. Nevertheless, we start to have scalability problems around 80k users.

---

#### The question

As mentioned before, due to performance concerns the attributes were all together put into a `user_attributes` table with one column per attribute. We've create a stored procedure (`create_user`) that takes all of the 60-70 attributes as arguments, create a record in the user table and then starts to select all other users, including their attributes, from the `user_attributes` table and starts to calculate the matching score with the final result being inserted into the newly created `UserXYZ_matches` table.

We now run a test to see how the setup performs (insert one user at time, until 300k users is reached) and it turns out that around 80k users, our CPU becomes the bottleneck. Though the test machines comes with 4 cores / 8 threads, only one is actually utilized. The problem is that the matching-per-other-user takes so long (PL/pgSQL performs really poor here), but the core issue is that all of these matchings happen on one CPU. For example, the matching against all other users could be split up into 8 different operations, each taking 1/8 of the `user_attributes` table records, performing the matching and inserting into the result table. We can optimize the badly performing PL/pgSQL, but I don't know a way on how to distribute the work across other CPU cores/threads.

---

#### Other Information

Please post recommendations on the approach as a whole as comments. I really appreciate advice on how to do better in general, but not as an answer to this specific question.

All of the user matching tables are stored within one tablespace which is backed by XFS and LVM striping across a couple of disks. The number of user matching tables (one per user) doesn't seem to be scalability problem (as we first thought). So disks are not a problem and the huge amount of tables seems to be covered by the specific setup.

A call/query to `create_user` should be atomic, i.e. transaction based. That's for our test-run, but doesn't need to be a hard requirement for the end product.

The create_user procedure basically looks like this (too long to post as a whole):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_user(...)
    -- (1) input_user = INSERT INTO user_attributes VALUES (parameter0, parameter1, ...)
    -- (2) create userXYZ_matching_table
    -- (3) FOR row IN SELECT * FROM "user_attributes" WHERE "id" <> input_user."id" LOOP
    --        -- repeat for every attribute
    --        IF row.this_attribute = input_user.this_attribute THEN
    --           match := match + 1
    --        END IF;       
    --        -- finally
    --        INSERT INTO userXYZ_matching_table VALUES (input.user.id, row.id, match)
    --     END LOOP;
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

I know that the high CPU usage comes from the amount of IF, ELSIF, END IF blocks (60-70). Again, this can be optimized but the question on how to scale such a stored procedure remains.

The server where the tests currently run on looks like below, which illustrates the problem pretty well:

[image: nmon output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge and documentation-reading abilities, PL/pgSQL does not support parallelism, nor does the server parallelize processing for individual queries.  I'm inclined to say, therefore, that scaling further will require parallelization at the *client* (new users inserted via multiple concurrent threads / processes with separate connections).

Overall, though, you have an inherent scaling problem in that to add a new record you need to compare it to all the other records.  The cost of doing that for N total records scales as N^2, and you're already pegging the CPU 25% of the way through.  Adding the 320,000th record will be four times as expensive as adding the 80,000th, and adding the 320,000 records in total will be at least *sixteen times* as expensive as adding 80,000.

It is conceivable that you could somewhat improve performance by using a `SELECT INTO` query instead of a stored procedure, but that won't improve the asymptotic complexity.  You could also consider creating the matching tables asynchronously, to improve the initial response.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm aware that this won't scale forever and to parallelize at client level was one thing I thought of. Just hoped that maybe there's a (postgres) trick where I could parallelize the FOR within the stored procedure...

Comment: @grasbueschel It won't just not scale forever, it will scale *extremely poorly* from *quite small user counts*. You need to completely rethink this, doing the matching asynchronously, effectively exploiting indexes, etc.

Comment: The create_user() function runs on the server. In fact, it runs a big fat loop on the server. I don't think parallelization on the client will help as much as the OP needs it to. I'm pretty sure the solution is going to require a different algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

(Elaborating on John's answer; please accept his not mine):

PL/PgSQL is probably a poor choice for this task.

It's slow for mathematical and logical operations. Very slow. PL/PgSQL is great for gluing a few SQL statements together - where most of the work is done by the SQL statements. It's terrible for lots of mathematical work and logic.

It also cannot exploit any CPU parallelism.

Additionally, running many individual small inserts like you do will be *extremely* slow. Don't do that. Instead, if you must do this in PL/PgSQL, have your function return a set of tuples for the results to be inserted, and call it as `INSERT INTO target_table SELECT * FROM my_procedure(...)` or similar. It'll be a lot faster.

Doing the work synchronously as part of the user insert makes the whole thing a lot worse, because the issues are more visible to the user. Particularly because, as John notes, this scales at O(N<sup>2</sup>), i.e. quadratically.

Your design is completely nonviable and needs to be rethought from scratch.

I suggest an approach that relies on *fact tables*, like in a star schema. Each attribute is a "fact" about the user. Each fact table is a `(user_id, fact_value)` tuple. A composite index exists on `(user_id, fact_value)`.

When the user is inserted, mark their user record as pending matching with a flag in the user record its self, and insert entries into the fact tables for it in the same transaction you insert the user.

Then have your application process a queue of users pending matching asynchronously as a background task. Join on the fact tables to find users who are most similar, i.e. with the most facts with the most similar values. Your application can exploit multiple PostgreSQL connections for parallelism, either processing multiple users at once or doing partial joins to produce interim results in temp table that you then join to find the final results.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and the hints! I missed to state that the test is about to get the limit at which synchronous inserts are just too slow and there's no way around doing it asynchronously. PL/PgSQL is not a requirement, but having this at the DB level seems to make sense (i.e. we could switch to another language). Also the problem will always stay O(N²) since I have to match each user against each other....

Comment: @grasbueschel You should be able to achieve something closer to O(n log n) with appropriate data structures, algorithms and index use. The trick is to ensure that each new user doesn't have to repeat all the work for each previous user, just use the already normalized attribute data via appropriate b-tree index scans.

Answer (score 0):

It a old tread and a interesting read. I came across this when i was trying to find if we can use threads kind of mechanism inside a SP.

The design explained in this thread of discussion (not sure if this is still relevant), what we can do is keep the insert in user table in one stored procedure and all the logic to create user_attribute table and population it can be move to a triggers.
Not sure if you can devise flow for multilevel triggers as per your design.
Downside is it may increase the number of fail points.. but once tested well should just do the trick..